# Cartesian reference systems rotation

Tags: geometry, rotations

I have 2 cartesian reference systems A and B with the same origin and I know the axes versors of both of them.
I have some points on A (Pa1, Pa2, ...) and I must rotate A (and Pa1, Pa2, ..) until A=B and get the new coordinations of Pa1, Pa2,...

Could someone tell me how it is possible to do this?

Comment: Use matrix rotations or quaternions. Are you in 2D or 3D?

Comment: I think you should start by finding the *angle* between A and B

Comment: @AdrianKeister 3D

Answer (score 1):

Form a matrix by taking the versors of $B$ in the basis of $A$. This matrix is the rotation matrix that applies $A$ to $B$. (This assumes that the basis are are orthonormal.)

Then it suffices to apply the matrix to the points in $A$.